# Move a circle to the top right of a font awesome bell

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have got a font-awesome bell and I am trying to make a bell appear on the top right of the bell.
Here is an example of what I want made in paint.NET
https://gyazo.com/2d74f611e2df81362bc3f2e946f9d747

And here is what I have tried so far:

```css
.notification {
 background: red;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 8px;
 width: 8px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<i class='fa fa-bell notification'></i>
```

But this puts the bell on the left side. I tried :before but it just made it disappear.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `position: relative;` to the `<i>`-tag and then in your CSS add:

```
.notification:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :after instead of :before, because font-awesome uses :before to display the actual font icon